# Amazon onebox thumbnail picture is broken

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, amazon

I posted an Amazon onebox [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5702489#5702489), and this is the result:

> [image]

The onebox thumbnail points to [this URL](http://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51SuPiOnyIL._SL160_.jpg), which does not exist.

If it matters, the original URL which was oneboxed is:

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Double-Shadow-Sally-Gardner/dp/1780225059
```

Can this please be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the image address is rendered as `//images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/...`, but that server does not serve unsecured images. The OneBox rendered link doesn't specify a protocol, so it uses whatever your browser used to access the page

If you access *SE chat* via `https` the images work. If you access chat via `http` they don't. It's probably a better idea to access chat over a secure connection in general, but that URL is just broken. There is no such resource as

`http://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51SuPiOnyIL._SL160_.jpg`

but that's what the OneBox will render if your chat connection is unsecured. It should always use `https` in the OneBox. That url:

`https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51SuPiOnyIL._SL160_.jpg`

works fine.

Comment: hi amazon oneboxing in chat seems completely broken for me right now any idea? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43501938#43501938