# Amazon oneboxing broken in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, amazon

It seems like Amazon oneboxing in chat is broken completely at the moment. Even tried links that previously oneboxed that don't onebox any more.

Here are some test links:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1?m=43501938#43501938

This is another defect on images broken in the onebox from 2017, but this current issue seems to be larger, and not the same.

[Amazon onebox thumbnail picture is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290124/amazon-onebox-thumbnail-picture-is-broken)

Comment: Old onebox still works on Tavern: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6473094#6473094.

Comment: yeah, it seems like `AWSECommerceService` doesn't love us at the moment, and is 400-ing us; this might be because we have failed to update to their current APIs, but until we can find time to dig deeper than "yup, definitely failing with a 400" it is hard to say.

Comment: @Marc thanks, maybe until this is fixed disable amazon onebox completely, i.e. don't try to onebox amazon links?

Comment: @MarcGravell hey, did you have a chance to dig deeper?

Comment: @ShadowWizard not yet; ultimately, Amazon oneboxing isn't top of our P1/P0 list, and we've been busy trying to launch "teams" :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Any change coming up on three years?