# YouTube Oneboxing Broken

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, youtube

[Twitter Oneboxing in chat appears broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328280/twitter-oneboxing-in-chat-appears-broken), and now YouTube links don't onebox as well ([1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50529708#50529708), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50529675#50529675)). Making bigger neaters things in chat to click is very important! Could someone look into this, please?

[SE posts seem to onebox fine.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50529722#50529722)

Answer (score 6):

**This is *not* an official statement from Google.**

I strongly suspect this was related to [a large scale networking outage](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/inside-google-cloud/an-update-on-sundays-service-disruption) which affected numerous Google products and services, including YouTube. The outage is now mitigated.